# i want to use the MY_Upload in library for codeingiter 3 but it error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i want to use the `MY_Upload` in library to do `multi_upload` images in codeigniter version 3 but it  error the message like that Message: Declaration of `MY_Upload::initialize()` should be compatible with `CI_Upload::initialize(array $config = Array, $reset = true)`. please help thanks

This is my controller

```
public function add_pagekage_values(){

    if($this->input->post("add")){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Pagekage Name', 'required|xss_clean|encode_php_tags');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'required|xss_clean|encode_php_tags');
        $this->load->library('MY_Upload');
        $this->load->library('upload');
        $this->upload->initialize(array(
            "upload_path"   => "./images/pagekage_image/",
            'file_name'=>'files',
            'allowed_types'=>"gif|png|jpg|png|GIF|PNG|JPG",
            'encrypt_name'=>true
        ));

        if($this->upload->do_multi_upload("files")){
           $last_data = $this->upload->get_multi_upload_data();
           $this->admin_model->add_product_value($last_data);
           redirect('admin_controller/pagekage');
        }else{
           $this->session->set_flashdata(array('already'=>'Please choose file to upload.....!!!'));
            redirect('admin_controller/add_pagekage');
        }

    }
}
```

This is my model

```
public function add_product_value($img = false){

        $this->db->insert("tbl_package",array(
            "p_name"=>$this->input->post("name"),
            'price'=>$this->input->post("price"),
            'discount'=>$this->input->post('dis'),
            'dis_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'p_decription'=>$this->input->post('editor1'),
            'supply_id'=>pde($this->input->post('supplyer')),
            'p_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'userid'=>$this->session->userdata("userID"),
            'auto'=>$this->input->post('auto')
        )); 
        $getID = mysql_insert_id();
        if($img){
            $n = 1;
            foreach($img as $key){
                if($n<=3):
                    $this->db->insert('tbl_photo',array(
                        "pho_name"=>$key['file_name'],
                        'id_pk'=>$getID
                    ));
                endif;
                $n++;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a difference in the error reporting level in CI3. You may be able to use the library by simply changing the signature of the method as implied by the error message.

Since the method doesn't seem to call the parent, it's really up to you whether the second parameter is implemented properly in the extending class (though you may want to document it in case you, or someone else, may need to update your site in the future).

[`MY_Upload` GitHub](https://github.com/avenirer/MY_Upload) `<!--Source code-->`
[`MY_Upload` Readme.txt](https://github.com/avenirer/MY_Upload/blob/master/README.md)  `<!--Installation File-->`

Example
Your view looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Upload multiple files</h1>
    <?php echo form_open_multipart(controller/add_pagekage_values);?>
    <p>Upload file(s):</p>
    <?php echo form_error('uploadedimages[]'); ?>
    <?php echo form_upload('uploadedimages[]','','multiple'); ?>
    <br />
    <br />
    <?php echo form_submit('submit','Upload');?>
    <?php echo form_close();?>
</body>
</html>
```

controller(Upload part)

```
if ($this->input->post()) {
    $config = array(
        'upload_path' => './upload/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
        'max_size' => '2048'
    );
    // load Upload library
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->do_upload('uploadedimages');
```

Comment: If this help please **[ACCEPT** it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution. Open up the `MY_Upload.php` file which you have stored inside your `application/library` folder.

Your method should look like this:

```
public function initialize($config = array()){
```

Replace the whole above line with this:

```
public function initialize(array $config = array(), $reset = true){
```